# How can I get selected item value in Angular 2 Material Autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material2

I have created an autocomplete field with Angular Material and getting country list from web api succesfully.

CountryID -> item value(or index)

Country -> item text

When I try to get selected item's value (not text) it return the text as expected. But I need to get selected item's value.

This is my code:

```js
this.WeatherSearchForm.get('country').value; // this returns the selected country name, ex: France
```

and

```xml
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Select Country..." [mdAutocomplete]="auto" class="form-control validate filter-input" formControlName="country">
</md-input-container>
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" md-input-name="autocompleteField" required md-input-minlength="2" md-input-maxlength="18"
  md-select-on-match required md-input-minlength="2">
  <md-option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" [value]="country.Country">
    {{ country.Country }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Edit:
After I changed this line

```xml
<md-option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" [value]="country.Country">
```

to this,

```xml
<md-option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" [value]="country.CountryID">
```

it worked fine, `this.WeatherSearchForm.get('country').value;` returned the CountryID.

But in UI side after selecting a country in the autocomplete field now I see the CountryID not Country.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add the code of the UI element showing the ID now (the one one the right with 6).

Comment: Actually this is the code showing 6, <md-option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" [value]="country.CountryID">

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `[displayWith]="displayFn"` inside `<md-autocomplete>` tag. Also, you have a pass the whole object as `value`.

```xml
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" md-input-name="autocompleteField" required md-input-minlength="2" md-input-maxlength="18"
  md-select-on-match required md-input-minlength="2" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <md-option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" [value]="country">
    {{ country.Country }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

In your compoent, add:

```js
displayFn(country): string {
      return country ? country.Country : country;
}
```

You can read more about it from **Setting separate control and display values** section in [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5wrr1YGxBzAFPj0sJgzT?p=preview)

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. As far as I see country is null in displayFn function. I also checked the docs and I believe it may not work as well because we don't send any user object in function parameters.

Comment: Have you checked the demo? It should work, if you are passing [value]="country". You don't have to pass 'user' for display Fn to work, it's taking 'country' object instead.

Comment: The problem is I cannot get the selectedvalue. if I set to CountryID like this: [value]="country.CountryID" then this.WeatherSearchForm.get('country').value returns Malta not 6 and display value is 6 not Malta. If I set this: [value]="country.Country" then display value is correct which is Malta. But this.WeatherSearchForm.get('country').value return Malta not 6.

Comment: I figured out now. Thanks for your help. I passed the object instead of value.  <md-option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" [value]="country"> and displayFn is same. displayFn(country): string {
    debugger;
    return country ? country.Country : country.CountryID;
  } And when I try to get the value I have casted to Country object and get the CountryID like this:   this.SavetoDB(this.WeatherSearchForm.get('country').value, ....          SavetoDB(country:Countries, .....           parseInt(country.CountryID)

Comment: Can I call other function inside displayFn? It returns me error

Comment: value should be object , thanks, you saved me .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final working version, hope it helps anyone else:

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" md-input-name="autocompleteField" required md-input-minlength="2" md-input-maxlength="18"
  md-select-on-match required md-input-minlength="2" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <md-option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" [value]="country">
    {{ country.Country }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>

selectedCountry:Countries;
displayFn(country: Countries): string {
  this.selectedCountry = country;
  console.log(this.selectedCountry);
  return country ? country.Country : country.CountryID;
}

this.SavetoDB(this.WeatherSearchForm.get('country').value);

SavetoDB(country:Countries)
{
   countryID = parseInt(country.CountryID);
...
```