# Angular 2 Autocomplete to fetch value from selected option

Tags: angular5, angular-material-5

In angular material, autocomplete feature mat-option will have same entries on "value" field and text within.

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="50">
   <input type="text" placeholder="{{label.addUser.formLabels.role}}"   matInput [matAutocomplete]="role"  formControlName="roleId">
   <mat-autocomplete  #role="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of roleListFilter | async" value="{{option.roleId}}" >
     <span>{{option.roleName}}</span>
    </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

and I get the output as shown in the following question..

[How can I get selected item value in Angular 2 Material Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016941/how-can-i-get-selected-item-value-in-angular-2-material-autocomplete)

I want to display selected string in the text box and set roleId in value field at the same time.. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" 
      [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="your_ctrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
       <mat-option (click)="getSelectedElementId(item.id)" *ngFor="let item of your_list | async" 
          [value]="item.name">
          <span>{{ item.name }}</span> |
       </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

In .ts file:

```
getSelectedElementId(id){
    console.log(id)
}
```

Comment: feature which I am using is not <mat-select> its <mat-autocomplete> if we add this [value]="option.value"  , on selection this value will be displayed in the textbox instead of "option.name"

Comment: Ok but as per official document the above code is working

Comment: Can you produce a plucker?

Comment: Here is the official documentation https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but my question was to have [value] = "item.id" instead of [value]="item.name" .. and whatever we enter in value field will be displayed in the text box.. so how can I fetch id of each options on select..

Comment: Do you want that value in your ts file then you can define a function for mat-option like I edited in the answer

Comment: Yes this can be done.. but this is one of the fields in my form , so when we use formGroup, how will this Id be fetched?

Comment: Use ngModel then

Comment: For particular control

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173332/discussion-between-varsha-bommarabettu-and-prashant-pimpale).